# Share a virtual environment between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy, virtualenv, buildozer

I am developing a kivy app in python using vscode with a virtual environment, everything works fine until I try to create an apk for Android.

Buildozer installs fine, but only works in Linux. So I am using the "Windows Terminal" Linux shell to do the apk build steps using buildozer. The problem is I cannot get the Linux shell to activate the virtual environment set up in windows/vscode and which is usually activated by running `venv/Scripts/activate`.

How do I activate this environment from "Windows Terminal" so vscode and Linux are sharing the same venv.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: There should be different files named activate in the Scripts folder, run the one you need for your environment like the `bat` for windows terminal, `ps1` for powershell, and the one with no extension for linux.

Comment: Oh one more thing, I don't know what you mean by sharing but the proper way of doing this is using `pip freeze` to get the packages installed on the original environment and then creating a new venv wherever you're transferring the project and install the packages you had from the original.

Comment: Linux in virtual environment will have programs and modules which can work only on Linux - especially if they use C/C++ modules which are compiled only for Linux. If you want to use on Windows then you would create new virtual environment and install modules which will work on Window (and will use C/C++ modules compiled for Windows). You can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save names of modules used on Linux and later on Windows use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the same modules in new virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you, so basically I should maintain a completely separate windows environment for development in vscode and a linux environment for apk build and deployment.